# How to drive an open drain/collector?

Tags: gpio, open-drain

I'm connecting a Digi XBee radio to a Kinetis microcontroller and would like to know how to control reset. The [XBee datasheet](https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/pdfs/90000982.pdf) describes the reset pin 5 as both input and open drain output:
[image: XBee datasheet]

Additionally, the Kinetis GPIO port controller can configure pins as either push/pull or open-drain output:
[image: Kinetis datasheet]

I think that to reset the radio, I need to do the following:

1. Not configure the pin direction (input/output) at boot, effectively leaving it floating.
2. To start reset, configure the pin as output and enable open drain.
3. Wait for at least 200ns.
4. Reconfigure the pin as input.
5. Wait for the radio to drive the pin low.

Is that right, or should I drive the pin low at step 2 instead of enabling open drain? Also, is my reasoning correct that the radio will eventually drive the pin low, so I should reconfigure the pin as input and poll until that happens?

I just want to clarify this as I've wasted a lot of time on similar issues before.

Comment: you need step 2a. --- output low on pin .... it may be that the XBee pulls reset low as a response to some event

Comment: please add a link to the XBee datasheet

Comment: @jsotola as requested: https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/pdfs/90000982.pdf (page 18)